# How to minify/obfuscate separate JS modules in a way that will support the API between them?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

Say I have 2 separate modules, in separate projects, each with its own build process.
These modules have some API between them, for example module `A` knows that modules `B` exports some function `foo` and uses it by `require('B').foo()`.

I want to minify these modules **before** publishing to `npm`, meaning I want the published code to be minified.

So I need the API to be minified in the same way, to use the same names. For example - if `export function foo()` becomes `export function x()` after minification in module `B`, then I need `require('B').foo()` in module `A` to become `require('B').x()` after minification.

I need to tell the minifier how to map the names of specific API funcitons and properties: `foo -> x` etc.

Is there any tool that allows to do this?

Comment: UMD modules, maybe webpack build?

Comment: @MartinChaov I'm not sure what you mean. Does it matter what type of module I am using? Also, AFAIK `webpack` is not a minifier, it can be used with different minify tools. Which one do you mean?

Comment: There is generally uglification and minification in webpack production builds, but UMD = universal module definition can help you achieve what you want. And yes, webpack can build such modules. Check this: https://github.com/mchaov/plugins-with-typescript-mobx-and-react/blob/master/.configs/webpack.shared.js